# Default MPVolumeView Style

Tags: ios6, mpvolumeview

Why iOS 6 SDK still uses old MPVolumeView control's style. I want to use default style like in Apple's Default Music application.

Old one:
[image]

New one:

[image]

Is there any way to use new one in my project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an another way to do this without using an UISlider control.

```
UIImage *minImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-bg"];
UIImage *maxImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-bg-active"];
UIImage *tumbImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"circle"];

// 276 x 14 px images used for min and max
// so i need to make the images into very small images by making resizable otherwise it strechs very ugly
minImage = [minImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0)];
maxImage = [maxImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 20)];

[volumeManager setMinimumVolumeSliderImage:minImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[volumeManager setMaximumVolumeSliderImage:maxImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[volumeManager setVolumeThumbImage:tumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And volumeManager is

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MPVolumeView *volumeManager;
```