# Set right and left image on UISlider iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I'm using MPVolumeView to show volume control in my app. I'd like to put right and left volume image to tell the meaning of the slider. (as it said on iOS Human Interface Guidelines).

Do I have to make two UIImageView on storyboard, create my own UIImage with photoshop and put them into the view or could I use a built-in method to do it?

**edit:**

Here it's what i'm doing.
The UISlider appear and work, but not my speaker image. (I've put them into Images.xcassets)

```
   _mpVolumeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    MPVolumeView * myVolumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:_mpVolumeView.bounds];
    [myVolumeView setMinimumVolumeSliderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"speakerMute"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myVolumeView setMinimumVolumeSliderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"speakerMax"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_mpVolumeView addSubview:myVolumeView];
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand. The `setMinimumVolumeSliderImage` and ``setMaximumVolumeSliderImage` changes the look of the actual slider bar. If you want to show little icons to the left and right of the slider, that is a totally separate need and not part of the volume view. You need create two `UIImageView` and add them on either side of the volume view.

Comment: Why is it possible on UISlider so ?
this code works and do what I want:
`_slider.minimumValueImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"speakerMute"];
 _slider.maximumValueImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"speakerMax"];`

Comment: Then I guess I'm confused by your question. Are you trying to customize the actual slider bar or are you trying to add icon images before and after the slider? BTW - In the code you posted in your answer you are calling `setMinimumVolumeSliderImage:` for both the min and max.

Comment: I'm trying to do what this :
`_slider.minimumValueImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"speakerMute"]; _slider.maximumValueImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"speakerMax"];` but with a MPVolumeView. Because I can't take a UISlider to change the volume of the device, i have to pass by MPVolumeView

Comment: Then the code you posted is mostly right. just change the 2nd call to `setMinimumVolumeSliderImage:` to `setMaximumVolumeSliderImage:`.

Comment: It doesn't work. I didn't get any picture of speaker on the mpvolumeview

Comment: The code you told me to use work to custom mpvolumeview like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001655/default-mpvolumeview-style. There is no speakers image there.

Comment: You really are confused. You keep saying two different things. The code in your question does NOT add any icons. It customizes the actual slider bar. I asked you if you wanted to add icons and you said no. Now you state that the icons don't appear. As I said earlier, if you want icons to appear next to the slider you need to add your own image views. `MPVolumeView` does NOT support adding icons.

Comment: 'MPVolumeView does NOT support adding icons' Ok, that what I was asking. Thanks.
I never told you that I don't want to add icons, I said I'd like to have the same result that I had with UISlider but on MPVolumeView.
Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties you're going to set are `maximumValueImage` and `minimumValueImage` both of which are `UIImage`'s.

From the docs:

> The image you specify should fit within the bounding rectangle
>   returned by the maximumValueImageRectForBounds: method. If it does
>   not, the image is scaled to fit. In addition, the receiver’s track is
>   lengthened or shortened as needed to accommodate the image in its
>   bounding rectangle.
>
> This default value of this property is nil.

Assuming you meet the size requirements writing `yourSlider.minimumValueImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.jpg"];` and then the same for the max value image is enough to get you going.

Comment: so, it's my responsibility to make the image ? iOS sdk doesn't provide it ?

Comment: @bobby Correct, you'll need to provide your own images.

Comment: Actually, i'm getting some trouble to get the UISlider of MPVolumeView object. I can't find any method to access it.

Comment: In that case you'll want to use the `- (void)setMinimumVolumeSliderImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state` set of methods.

Comment: I edited my question, to show you the code I made. I tried to set minimumValueImage on a UISlider and it work properly, but not on MPVolumeView